# XML in Python and lxml

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I am using the pinnacle (betting) api which returns an XML file. At the moment, I save it to a .xml file as below:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
responseData = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

ofn = 'pinnacle_feed_basketball.xml'
with open(ofn, 'w') as ofile:
    ofile.write(responseData)
parse_xml()
```

and then open it in the parse_xml function

```
tree = etree.parse("pinnacle_feed_basketball.xml")
fdtime = tree.xpath('//rsp/fd/fdTime/text()')
```

I am presuming saving it as an XML file and then reading in the file is not necessary but I cannot get it to work without doing this.

I tried passing in `responseData` to the `parsexml()` function

```
parse_xml(responseData)
```

and then in the function

```
tree = etree.parse(responseData)
fdtime = tree.xpath('//rsp/fd/fdTime/text()')
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to parse an in-memory object (in your case, a string), use `etree.fromstring(<obj>)` -- `etree.parse` expects a file-like object -- [Docs](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse an in-memory object (in your case, a string), use `etree.fromstring(<obj>)` -- `etree.parse` expects a file-like object or filename -- [Docs](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsers)

For example:

```
import urllib2, lxml.etree as etree

url = 'http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/note.xml'
headers = {}

req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
responseData = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

element = etree.fromstring(responseData)
print(element)
print(etree.tostring(element, pretty_print=True))
```

Output:

```
<Element note at 0x2c29dc8>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`parse()`](http://parsers) is designed to read from [**file-like objects**](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-file-object).

But you are passing a string in both cases - `pinnacle_feed_basketball.xml` string and `responseData`, which is also a string.

In the first case it should be:

```
with open("pinnacle_feed_basketball.xml") as f:
    tree = etree.parse(f)
```

In the second case:

```
root = etree.fromstring(responseData)  # note that you are not getting an "ElementTree" object here
```

---

FYI, `urllib2.urlopen(req)` is *also a file-like object*:

```
tree = etree.parse(urllib2.urlopen(req))
```